# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}=0.$$

---

Let $a_n= \dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}$. My initial thought was to use the direct comparison test $$\frac{1}{n^2}< a_n < b_n$$ but I cannot find a $b_n > a_n:  b_n = 0$.

For example I tried $$b_n= \left( \frac{n!}{n} \right)^n =((n-1)!)^n \to \infty.$$

Any ideas on how to find a proper $b_n$ or other approaches to prove this limit?

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: Use Stirling's Formula.

Comment: You don't need the full power of Stirling's formula: the limit of $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ is quite obviously zero, so the same applies to the $n$-th power of such positive ratio.

Comment: $$ \frac{n!}{n^n}=\text{GM}(1/n,2/n,\ldots,n/n)^n\leq \text{AM}(1/n,2/n,\ldots,n/n)^n=\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)^n\to 0.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio With respect to your 1st comment (above): nice analysis; I upvoted.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232488/limit-almost-finished-however-hint-needed and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017081/limit-with-factorial-and-power

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have

$$\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}=\left(\frac{n!}{n^{n}}\right)^n \leq \left(\frac1{n}\right)^n\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}=\left(\frac{n!}{n^{n}}\right)^n\to 0$$

indeed by ratio test

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^{n}}{n!}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\to \frac1e \implies \frac{n!}{n^{n}}\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $0<n!/n^n\le1$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}n\log(n!/n^n)=-\infty$ and taking exponentials yields the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n=\frac{(n!)^n}{n^{n^2}}\implies \log(a_n)=n \log(n!)-n^2 \log(n)$$ Using Stirling approximation
$$\log(a_n)=-n^2+\frac{1}{2} n \log (2 \pi  n)+\frac{1}{12}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$n! <(1)(2) (n^{n-2})$ so $(n!)^{n} <2^{n} (n^{n(n-2)})$. Take $b_n=2^{n}n^{-2n}$. Note that $b_n <(\frac 1  2)^{n}$ if $n >2$